# Choosing between AWS Batch(Fargate Compute Environment) with EventBridge Scheduler and AWS Fargate with Scheduler for a Java Task Scheduler

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, scheduling, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I have a Java task scheduler that runs approximately 6 hours per day on AWS. I'm considering two deployment options and seeking advice on which one is more suitable for my use case:

**Option 1: AWS Batch(Fargate Compute Environment) with EventBridge Scheduler**

**Option 2: AWS Fargate with Scheduler**

I would like to know the pros and cons of each option to make an informed decision. Any insights or recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using AWS Batch already? Do you need the features of AWS Batch? Both of your solutions use the same scheduler (EventBridge) and the same compute environment (Fargate), one just has the extra features of AWS Batch, while the other uses regular ECS.

Comment: Hey Mark B, currently we are doing some poc to check whether which one is fit for requirment.  Our simple scheduler doesnt need any complex tracking.  Based on your input, i beleive the cost for running the scheduler is same ryt

Comment: The price would be exactly the same either way, since they are both running on Fargate.

Comment: I tend to agree that if your needs are simple then just use EB + Fargate. If you are finding that tasks do need retry capability, then look to Batch. Another case would be when you need to balance a limited set of resources across a few different types of jobs, then Batch's fair share scheduling may be good to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I created an Aws batch fargate  with EventBridge Scheduler to schedule a lot of tasks, like as Report sending, export data, insert data, and works fine, but we had a problems between EventBridge and Aws batch. Imagine you create a schedules in EventBridge with a Batch Job Definition number 1, after that you created a new version from Job definition for instance version 2, with a bugfix. All EventBridge created before, it'll run with job definition version 1, in other words with a bug

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

AWS batch vs AWS ECS (Fargate)
To decide about wich one you will use, schedule mechanism is not an important feature.

[https://stackshare.io/stackups/aws-batch-vs-aws-fargate#:~:text=With%20AWS%20Fargate%2C%20you%20no,%22Containers%20as%20a%20Service%22](https://stackshare.io/stackups/aws-batch-vs-aws-fargate#:%7E:text=With%20AWS%20Fargate%2C%20you%20no,%22Containers%20as%20a%20Service%22).

Comment: You can use fargate to run aws batch. The actual scenario is, to run a scheduler aws fargate or aws batch with fargate which one suitable